# Unknown TCP in the nethogs output

Tags: networking, command-line

The `nethogs` command displayes programs attending network communication.

```
There is a permanent line:
PID USER PROGRAM      DEV  SENT  RECEIVED
?   root unknown TCP  eth0 0.000 0.000 KB/sec
```

Why `nethogs` displays such a row and what does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not care about the `unknown` program it is a fake process , there is the answer of 
the `nethogs` [developer's](https://sourceforge.net/p/nethogs/bugs/17/)

> The 'unknown TCP' line is normal: it collects all TCP traffic that we were unable to relate to any actual process.